# Proper way to store Image-info in RavenDb without using attatchments

Tags: ravendb

I've read a lot abuot storing images with attatchments. But I wonder what's the right way is to store image-INFO in ravenDb. So I then can use the info and get the image from some online-storage.
I think i need the path.. maybe, with, height and so on... So what is the right way of doing this in the raven dbDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your requirements my basic answer is something like:

```
public class Image
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the original name of the Image.
    /// </summary>
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the physical location of the Image 
    /// </summary>
    public string Location {get; set;}

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the size of the file.
    /// </summary>
    public long FileSize { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the MIME type of the file.
    /// </summary>
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Width, in pixels, of the Image
    /// </summary>
    public int Width { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Height, in pixels, of the Image
    /// </summary>
    public int Height { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the thumbnails.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The thumbnails.
    /// </value>
    public ICollection<Thumbnail> Thumbnails { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the last Thumbnail id.
    /// </summary>

    public int LastThumbnailId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the new Thumbnail id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int GenerateNewThumbnailId()
    {
        return ++LastThumbnailId;
    }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Thumbnail id.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Width, in pixels, of the Thumbnail
    /// </summary>
    public int Width { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Height, in pixels, of the Thumbnail
    /// </summary>
    public int Height { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the physical location of the Thumbnail 
    /// </summary>
    public string Location {get; set;}
}
```